# Programatically add configurable products to cart in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add configurable products to cart for my mobile app for magento site. i have tried various solutions but fail to add. please help me. or suggest any rest api for add to cart functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check product website id and current store website id whether they match or not.

Refer this file:  **core/mage/checkout/model/cart.php**

```
$currentWebsiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    if (!$product
        || !$product->getId()
        || !is_array($product->getWebsiteIds())
        || !in_array($currentWebsiteId, $product->getWebsiteIds())
    ) {
      Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('The product could not be found.'));
    }
    return $product;
```